# How to get instance of class that uses dependency injection in its constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, components, vaadin

Ok, so the title might not be the best but bare with me here. So my Vaadin application is one page with no other routes. Although the web application is one page, I chose to split the page into different classes depending on the layout, etc. There is one main class called MainLayout.class which has the @Route("").

[image: Screenshot of the web application]

**Here is a general outline of the website and each outline represents a new class that extends some time of component. (Bottom half missing to maintain simplicity.)**

Now the issue with this is that both the Red and Blue componenets use dependency injection to inject the needed services. That is all fine, but the issue comes when the **purple** layout wants to hold the instances of both the Red and Blue classes so that it could add the components to itself.

**My Current Approach:**
My current approach which feels very hacky and wrong is just using dependency injection again by injecting the blue and the red component classes to the constructor of the purple class. This process continues up until it reaches the MainLayout class.

**My Question:**
Is there any other possible solution to this problem and if so, how or where could I go about fixing the issue?

**Main Layout Class:** (It is using dependency injection to get all the other sub-layouts that also contain sub componenets, etc.)

```java
@Route("")
@PageTitle("Ur Weather App")
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final NavigationView searchBar;
    private final CurrentInfoLayout currentInfoLayout;
    private final MoreDetailInfoLayout moreDetailInfoLayout;

    @Autowired
    public MainLayout(NavigationView searchBar,
                        CurrentInfoLayout currentInfoLayout,
                        MoreDetailInfoLayout moreDetailInfoLayout) {
        this.searchBar = searchBar;
        this.currentInfoLayout = currentInfoLayout;
        this.moreDetailInfoLayout = moreDetailInfoLayout;
        addClassName("main-layout");

        add(this.searchBar, this.currentInfoLayout, this.moreDetailInfoLayout);
    }

}
```

**The Red Component:** (Blue component is similar in a way)

```java
@Component
@UIScope
@CssImport("./styles/current-info-styles.css")
public class CurrentDayView extends VerticalLayout {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private NowcastWeatherService nowcastWeatherService;
    private GeoLocationService geoLocationService;

    //Some other code here

    @Autowired
    public CurrentDayView(NowcastWeatherService nowcastWeatherService, GeoLocationService geoLocationService) {
        this.nowcastWeatherService = nowcastWeatherService;
        this.geoLocationService = geoLocationService;

        //Other functionality here
    }
    //Other code here
}
```

**The Purple Component:** (This is using dependency injection to get the other components.)

```java
@Component
@UIScope
@CssImport("./styles/current-info-styles.css")
public class CurrentInfoLayout extends HorizontalLayout {

    private CurrentDayView currentDayView;
    private CurrentTemperatureView currentTemperatureView;

    @Autowired
    public CurrentInfoLayout(CurrentDayView currentDayView, CurrentTemperatureView currentTemperatureView) {
        this.currentDayView = currentDayView;
        this.currentTemperatureView = currentTemperatureView;
        this.searchBar = searchBar;

        //Other functionality here
    }
    //Other code here
}
```

As you can probably tell, I'm fairly knew to most of this stuff so I might not know the best strategy for dependency injection, etc.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is the problem? Please add the error/stacktrace you get or how this does not behave like you think it would.

Answer (score 0):

From the spring and dependency injection perspective(i have not worked with Vaadin), you are doing it right. You are injecting by constructor which is the recommended way. What you could do more is to add the `final` keyword to your injected attributes as you did in `MainLayout`.

If you want to avoid using dependency injection, you can use the `Singleton` pattern to retrieve the instance of the needed components when you instantiate a parent component.

Comment: Hmm ok. So let's say I have a component that uses a service and gets it through dependency injection. Everyone else that wants an instance of that class, that uses a service, will have to use dependency injection. This cycle would repeat until it reaches the "top-level" class. Doesn't that result in tightly coupled and heavily reliant classes? Shouldn't they be "loosely" coupled instead of being directly coupled which results from this?

Comment: Actually dependency injection comes in help to obtain loosely coupled classes, especially when you use interfaces instead of the actual implementation of the services.